# How to update dataframe row values based on multiple conditions in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

In pyspark I have the current dataframe, df_A:

```
+-------------+-------------+--------+-----------+--------+
|           id|         Type|id_count|     Value1|  Value2|
+-------------+-------------+--------+- ---------+--------+
|           18|          AAA|       2|      null|     null|
|           18|          CCC|       2|      null|     null|
|           16|          AAA|       2|      null|     null|
|           16|          BBB|       2|      null|     null|
|           17|          CCC|       1|      null|     null|
+-------------+-------------+--------+----------+---------+
```

I want to loop through every row and update the Value1 and Value2 based on condiftions.

- If id_count == 1 and Type == CCC i want to input a value to Value1 in
  this current row.
- If id_count == 2 and Type == CCC i want to input a value to Value1 in
  this current row.
- If id_count == 2 and Type == AAA i want to input a value to Value2 in
  this current row.

I have tried this with df.foreach and with rdd.map but im not able to update the values in the row. I do not undertand how to return a 'row' from the foreach to be updated in my existing dataframe.

What i have tried is somewhere along this line, using a test-string as value:

```
def update_row(row):
     row.Value1 = "test_value"
     return row

updated_df = df_A.foreach(lambda row: update_row(row)
```

- How to i updated the value?
- Should it return a row?
- If it returns a row, is it appended to the updated_df.

Can someone help me explain an approch on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a different approach what you need. First of all, to approach columns, you need to use the [.withColumn method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn.html) of the DataFrame. But you want not only to update, but to conditionally update. The function you need in this case is "when", which can be imported like this

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
```

Then, you would approach the problem in the following manner:

```
updated_df = df.withColumn("Value1", when(df.id_count == "1", "certain_value").otherwise(df.Value1))
```

This line of code would update the column "Value1" when id_count=1 into "certain_value", and will leave it as it was otherwise.

You just need to combine your conditions and values appropiately to get to your goal. [Here is a detailed explanation](https://www.statology.org/pyspark-update-column-value-based-on-condition/). Hope it helps.